# Explorer not loading conditional style-sheet in Wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

I have a wordpress site I am using ie conditional comments to load in an ie specific stylesheet in to. For some reason the changes made aren't being reflected in IE's rendering:

I have tried:

- clearing browser history
- deleting and re-uploading the file
- ensuring the conditional comment is correct
- closing all browsers and restarting
- checking the file path
- Adding php style now() to force refresh

And I've reached a point where I'm baffled.

What else can I try?

edit:

the code:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>K9 Heaven - 21st Century Dog Care</title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.k9heaven.org.uk/wp-content/themes/k9_0.2/style.css" />
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->

<link rel="pingback" href="http://www.k9heaven.org.uk/xmlrpc.php" />

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://www.k9heaven.org.uk/wp-content/themes/k9_0.2/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="K9 Heaven &raquo; Feed" href="http://www.k9heaven.org.uk/?feed=rss2" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="K9 Heaven &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://www.k9heaven.org.uk/?feed=comments-rss2" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="K9 Heaven &raquo; Home Comments Feed" href="http://www.k9heaven.org.uk/?feed=rss2&amp;page_id=49" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='NextGEN-css'  href='http://www.k9heaven.org.uk/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/css/nggallery.css?ver=1.0.0' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='shutter-css'  href='http://www.k9heaven.org.uk/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/shutter/shutter-reloaded.css?ver=1.3.2' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.k9heaven.org.uk/wp-includes/js/l10n.js?ver=20101110'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var shutterSettings = {
    msgLoading: "L O A D I N G",
    msgClose: "Click to Close",
    imageCount: "1"
};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.k9heaven.org.uk/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/shutter/shutter-reloaded.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.k9heaven.org.uk/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.6.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.k9heaven.org.uk/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js?ver=2.88'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.k9heaven.org.uk/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/js/ngg.slideshow.min.js?ver=1.05'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.k9heaven.org.uk/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.js?ver=20090102'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://www.k9heaven.org.uk/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://www.k9heaven.org.uk/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<link rel='index' title='K9 Heaven' href='http://www.k9heaven.org.uk' />
<link rel='prev' title='Contact' href='http://www.k9heaven.org.uk/?page_id=25' />
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.2.1" />

<!-- All in One SEO Pack 1.6.13.3 by Michael Torbert of Semper Fi Web Design[395,435] -->
<meta name="description" content="K9 Heaven - 21st Century Dog Care" />
<meta name="keywords" content="K9,Heaven,21st,Century,Dog,Care" />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.k9heaven.org.uk/" />
<!-- /all in one seo pack -->

<meta name='NextGEN' content='1.8.3' />
    <style type="text/css">.recentcomments a{display:inline !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}</style>

</head>
```

http://www.k9heaven.org.uk/

**Feel free to close this thread, forgot that relative css paths in wordpress themes go to the site root, not the theme root. And won the stupid hat.**

Comment: Can you post the code that's embedding your various stylesheets, or at least a link to the site?

Comment: Maybe you **are** loading the conditional CSS but your original CSS is  overriding it.

Comment: tracer, please post the solution as an answer and then "accept" your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this

```
http://www.k9heaven.org.uk/ie.css
```

the sheet you're tyring to load? or is it this:

```
http://www.k9heaven.org.uk/wp-content/themes/k9_0.2/ie.css
```

The code above is referencing the first style sheet at the root of the site. That's non-standard. You should use `<?php get_theme_root() ?>` in the style sheet link in the theme files to target the style sheet in the theme folder.